# Detecting Click Outside Element but Inside Parent

Tags: angular, typescript, navbar, navigationbar, angular-components

So I'm trying to be able to hide a navigation menu when you click anywhere other than the hamburger icon itself. I have it working so that the menu toggles between shown and hidden when you click the hamburger icon. It also hides the menu if you click on the page itself. The problem is that if you click on the navbar itself (but outside the hamburger icon), it won't hide the menu. I think I understand that this is because the handleClick() function is looking for the referring element to NOT contain the event target, but I'm not sure how to get around this and still make everything else work correctly.

Here is the component HTML file:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="toggleMenu()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">Job Matrix</a>
</nav>
<div class="form-row btn-group-vertical nav-menu-fixed" *ngIf="visible" [@fade-in-out]="state">
    <a class="btn btn-primary text-left item" href="#" role="button">Jobs</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary text-left item" href="#" role="button">Resumes</a>
</div>
```

Here is the angular component typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, group, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.scss'],
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
    },
    animations: [
        trigger('fade-in-out', [
            state('open', style({
                transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
            })),
            state('closed', style({
                transform: 'translate3d(0, -110%, 0)'
            })),
            transition('closed => open', animate('500ms ease-in')),
            transition('open => closed', animate('500ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
})

export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    [x: string]: any;

    visible: boolean;
    state: string;

    constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.visible = false;
        this.state = 'closed';
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.visible = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.state = this.state == "open" ? 'closed' : 'open';
        }, 50);
    }

    handleClick(event: Event) {
        if (!this.ref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.state = 'closed';
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.visible = false;
            }, 500);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the `ref` is giving you the entire host element (hamburger and menu), but it seems like you want to separate the menu (`.nav-menu-fixed`) and if the click was outside the menu (including the `.navbar-toggler`), close the menu. You can use the [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to get a hold of the menu itself, and check if the click contains the menu.

Add a ref (`#menu`) to your menu component:

```
<div #menu class="nav-menu-fixed" *ngIf="visible" [@fade-in-out]="state">
  <a class="btn btn-primary text-left item" href="#" role="button">Jobs</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary text-left item" href="#" role="button">Resumes</a>
</div>
```

Then use the `@ViewChild` decorator to query that menu element in the DOM.

```
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('menu', {read: ElementRef})
    menu: ElementRef;

    constructor() {}

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    handleClick(event: Event) {
     const menuIsOpen = this.visible && this.state === 'open';
     const toggleWasClicked = this.toggle.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
     const menuWasClicked = this.menu && this.menu.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
     const pageWasClicked = !toggleWasClicked && !menuWasClicked;
     const menuShouldClose = (pageWasClicked || toggleWasClicked) && menuIsOpen;

     if (menuShouldClose) {
         this.state = 'closed';
         setTimeout(() => {
             this.visible = false;
         }, 500);
     }
    }    
}
```

I used the [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator in my snippet instead of the `host` property because I think it's a nice way to keep the event listener close to the method that handles it :)

Comment: This give me an undefined error on the first line of the handleClick() function (on this.menu).

Comment: Did you define the `@ViewChild` property in your component class?

Comment: Oh I see, it's because the menu is only present in the DOM if `visible` is true. You'll need to add an extra check like `this.menu && this.menu.nativeElement...`

Comment: It would seem that this.menu is always undefined.  So if I check for undefined, then it still doesn't hide the menu when clicking on the navbar itself. If I don't check for undefined, then it hides the menu right after showing it, because the hamburger menu click triggers the hide also.

I did find a way to make it work with the way I was doing it before by slightly changing the handleClick function:

Comment: var clickedElement = this.ref.nativeElement;
        var parentElement = event.target.parentElement;

        if (!clickedElement.contains(event.target) || clickedElement == parentElement) {
            this.state = 'closed';
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.visible = false;
            }, 500);
        }

Comment: The issue of it closing when the hamburger menu item is clicked is actually due to the `setTimeout` rather than the clicking logic : / -- you will find that your approach also hides the menu as soon as the toggle is clicked. Check this Stackblitz to see both approaches achieving the same thing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle-menu-button (the approach I detailed in my answer using `@ViewChild` is `checkOne`, the approach you mentioned in your comment is `checkTwo`). It only works if you wait more than 500ms between clicks xD

Comment: You did achieve the same functionality a different way though, and doing so answered your own question :) Now you get to choose which approach you prefer.

Comment: Btw, I edited the above answer to have the correct checks for hiding the menu so you can actually choose between two working implementations. The check I had before was not enough.